# ld cannot find library even when ldconfig does

Tags: ld

There are several variations of this problem reported here and as far as I understand the responses, it boils down to the following causes:

- the software or its developer package is not installed
- ldconfig not knowing about the libraries
- missing compiler options that tell where to search the library
- wrong library names or missing soft links (libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.5)

Now I've got:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_regex
```

But ldconfig knows about it:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep boost_regex.so
    libboost_regex.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libboost_regex.so.5
    libboost_regex.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libboost_regex.so
```

and it also exists:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libboost_regex.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Sep 24 08:19 /usr/lib64/libboost_regex.so -> libboost_regex.so.5
$ ll /usr/lib64/libboost_regex.so.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1000224 Apr  2 09:48 /usr/lib64/libboost_regex.so.5
```

Any ideas or hints what I'm missing?

Regards,
Andi

Comment: I desperately need this answer too =(

Comment: I wanted to ask exactly the same question.
Moreover g++ links seamleassly the libraries, while ld doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcc - /usr/bin/ld error: cannot find <library> in /usr/local/lib though ldconfig list it, and path added to ld.so.conf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737996/gcc-usr-bin-ld-error-cannot-find-library-in-usr-local-lib-though-ldconfig)

Answer (score 0):

`-lboost_regex` option tells `ld` to search for `/usr/lib64/libboost_regex.so`. This is a symbolic link provided by a development package for boost-regex library.

On Fedora:

```
$ rpm -q --file /usr/lib64/libboost_regex.so
boost-devel-1.50.0-7.fc18.x86_64
```

On Ubuntu:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/libboost_regex.so
libboost-regex1.49-dev: /usr/lib/libboost_regex.so
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I hit the problem today too and wanted to share.

"ldconfig" is for *loading* libraries at runtime.  It has no effect on *linking* during build time.  I was surprised by that too.

Here are two solutions I found for the linking problem:

1. specify library directories when you build using -L
2. copy/move your libraries to a "standard" location like /usr/lib .  You could try symlinking but that didn't work for me.