# gcc - /usr/bin/ld error: cannot find <library> in /usr/local/lib though ldconfig list it, and path added to ld.so.conf

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ld

I try to compile a C++ code, using a library I've also compiled manually and installed in /usr/local/lib

The compilation of the software fails at the linking step:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lcppdb
```

it seems that g++ does not search by default in `/usr/local/lib` , same for `clang++`

```
 g++ -print-search-dirs # does not show /usr/local/lib
```

however the fact is `/usr/local/lib` is in my `/etc/ld.so.conf` and I did run `ldconfig` as root, and actually running `ldconfig -p | grep cppdb` shows me

```
libcppdb_sqlite3.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/local/lib/libcppdb_sqlite3.so.0
libcppdb_sqlite3.so (libc6) => /usr/local/lib/libcppdb_sqlite3.so
libcppdb.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/local/lib/libcppdb.so.0
libcppdb.so (libc6) => /usr/local/lib/libcppdb.so
```

adding the option `-L/usr/local/lib` of course solve the problem, but the goal is to use configuration files

Comment: @vidit sorry for the imprecision on it, but of course my actual code is using g++ otherwise it would not have gone so far as the linking step , I'm editing my question

Comment: Perhaps learn about [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ld`, the linker, does not use external configuration files for that. `ldconfig` is for the loader, `ld.so`. Create a makefile if you want to set values for the linker somewhere.

Comment: you mean there's no way to change that system wide? trough the mean of an environment variable or something like that?

Comment: Correct. Use a makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `-L` switches in your makefile is a common way to deal with this problem, but you can actually make system-wide changes by modifying the default GCC [spec file](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html), which can be used to specify additional options to be passed to the compiler, linker, etc. I've done this in the past to address your specific problem, but it was a long time ago, so I can't give you a specific example, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

1. You can use linker script, and add '/usr/local/lib' to search_dir.
   see this [Linker_Scripts](http://wiki.osdev.org/Linker_Scripts) to get more details.
2. add /usr/local/lib to GCC_EXEC_PREFIX shell environment, and try it again.
   more details search print-search-dirs in "man" of g++.

just suggestion, it has not yet tried.